# Default constructor C++ error

Tags: c++, constructor

I require help with respect to class construction. In my class, I have used a copy constructor and operator= to prevent the compiler from creating them. In my main program, when I try to create an instance of the class, I get an error saying "No default constructor exists for the class".

What could be the problem?

This is a snippet of my code.

```
class netlist {
    netlist(const netlist &);
    netlist &operator=(const netlist &);
    std::map<std::string, net *> nets_;
}; // class netlist
```

In my main function I am using:

```
netlist nl;
```

This is where I get the error. I am providing the copy constructor declaration, so they should not be a problem.

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question reveals another advantage of using a non-copyable and non-assignable base class: that wouldn't suppress the creation of an implicit default constructor. http://codepad.org/qejKEQoW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with the code -

1. class members are **private** by default.
2. `"I get an error saying "No default constructor exists for the class" ".`

Because if any kind of constructor is provided as a part of class declaration( `netlist` class has a copy constructor in this case), default constructor( i.e., constructor with no arguments ) is not provided by compiler.

```
netlist nl;  // And this invokes call to the default constructor and so
             // the error
```

---

**netlist.h**

```
class netlist {

public: // Added
    netlist(); // This just a declaration. Should provide the definition.
    netlist(const netlist &);
    netlist &operator=(const netlist &);
    std::map<std::string, net *> nets_;
}; // class netlist
```

**netlist.cpp**

```
netlist::netlist()
{
       // .....
}

// Other definitions
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahesh for your help! I didnt know this before. Now I understand.

Answer (score 6):

When you create the netlist you are not passing any arguments to the constructor which means you are calling a default constructor. However you didn't define a default constructor. You only created a constructor taking a different netlist as a parameter (the copy constructor) here:

```
netlist(const netlist &);
```

You should define a default constructor like this:

```
netlist();
```

Note that had you not defined any constructor, the compiler would have added default ones but since you added the copy constructor, you have to define all of them yourself.

Comment: But wait, doesn't the compiler generate a default constructor if none is provided?

Comment: Thanks....    But if I do that, I get this error:   >main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall netlist::netlist(void)" (??0netlist@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: @sista - That is because you didn't provide the definition for the default constructor. Its a linker error which means the definition is not found.

Comment: @Cameron It does but only if you define _no_ constructors. If you define a constructor of any type, the compiler won't automatically make a default one.

Comment: Thank you Cameron and quasiverse.

Answer (score 0):

section `[class.ctor]` of the standard says (wording from draft n3242):

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument.  If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).  An implicitly-declared default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

You have a user-declared constructor:

```
netlist(const netlist &);
```

thus the compiler does not provide a default constructor.